# Android Compatibility Error

Tags: nullpointerexception, android-manifest

I have an written an Android Application through Eclipse that has been tested/working on both the emulator and hardware devices for version 1.5, 1.6, and 2.1 (Although the Target Build was only set for 1.5)

The application fails to initialize on any version greater than 2.1 on the emulator and hardware devices.

All related posts seem to point towards the min and target sdk version.  I first tried changing the Target Build from 1.5 to 2.3.1 and included the min/target sdk xml tags, but this has not helped.

Attached is the debug error file (This error only occurs with emulators/phones > 2.1).  Any suggestions?

04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.project/com.test.project.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:211)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.view.View.(View.java:1814)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:103)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at com.test.project.Main$EfficientAdapter.(Main.java:34)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at com.test.project.Main.onCreate(Main.java:150)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-01 03:46:40.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


 <application
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" 
      android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
      android:label="@string/icon" 
      android:debuggable="true">

      <activity 
           android:name="Main"
           android:label="@string/app">

           <intent-filter>

                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

           </intent-filter>

      </activity>

      <activity android:name="CampusMapActivity"/>
      <activity android:name="FacultyActivity"/>
      <activity android:name="PhoneActivity"/>
      <activity android:name="RSSActivity"/>

 </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not respond this question.

I have found the error in my ways.

I was using the List14.java example provided on the Android Develpor API Demos.

I overlooked that the static class Viewholder() already provides a text/icon attribute.
I was declaring my own (additional/unnecessary) icon variable that conflicted with Viewholder().

What surprises me is that the phone emulators only crash when I'm using 2.2 and higher.
1.5 - 2.1 Android phones ignore??? the error.

Anyways by removing the conflicting variable, the application works across all emulators